# C# SerialDataReceivedEventArgs using with backgroundWorker1

Tags: c#

I work with serial port. I'm reading serial port data with        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs event.

In "myport_DataRecieved_Client" method, I read serial data into global string "porta".

I have scatter ScatterGraph component on the GUI (by NationalInstruments). When I receive a new line from serial port, in "doguiwork" method I'm parsing the data and add them to ScatterPlot (data plot shoved by ScatterGraph).

The problem is this, adding new data to ScatterPlot cause lags on GUI while new data continuously receiving (for a new line, data rate is 50 times per second) from serial port. So, I want to eliminate this lags.

Calling the method PlotXYAppend() that adds new data to ScatterPlot with Control.Invoke don't change the lagging situation.

```
    void myport_DataRecieved_Client(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        porta = sp.ReadLine();
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy==false)
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
     }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        doguiwork();

    }


   private void doguiwork()
    {

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        double db = double.Parse(words[yer[i]], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  scatterPlot[i].PlotXYAppend(x, db);
 }
     catch { }
     }
```

Comment: _"Is this way I gave below is correct?"_ -- no. Your question lack enough detail to be answerable, but you're far enough off track that we can at least know what you've got can't possibly be correct. `BackgroundWorker` isn't there to do _"gui operations"_. It's there to do things _other_ than GUI operations. You should probably just be using `Control.Invoke()` in your `DataReceived` event handler, to update the UI based on the data received. But if you want better advice, you need to post a better question. Before you attempt that, try doing some research first.

Comment: Which details I need to do add more? I already tried using Control.Invoke() for not locking down the GUI but it doesn't changed the situation. I already read a lot of questions and answers on here about serial port reading and GUI update. Still no luck. With this way I'm asking here my GUI isn't blocking but serial port communication is slowing down to 1/3. Its better than blocking.

Comment: you have it backwards.  you do the long running task in `DoWork` not updaing the UI

Comment: _"Which details I need to do add more?"_ -- see [mcve]. Also read [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I will add more details

Comment: It is a standard fire-hose problem.  You *must* remove old points from the series when you add points.  Given that ~200 points is usually enough to display accurate data, you probably have lots of leeway to make it faster.  If that still doesn't help then you have to filter, delete points that are not necessary to make the graph any more accurate.  If that still doesn't help then you have to drop data.

Comment: @Hans I know this already but have I todo this? Is the history capacity isn't capable to hold more data alive?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with "history capacity", only the amount of CPU cycles that the UI thread burns matter.  No you don't have to do this, people can usually tell the UI programmer's skill from ten feet away.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll lol for you by the way